# Intersection Volume

Tags: geometry, volume

Given that P is a square pyramid whose base consists of the four vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(3,0,0)$, $(3,3,0)$, and $(0,3,0)$, and whose apex is the point $(1,1,3)$.

Then let Q be a square pyramid whose base is the same as the base of P, but whose apex is the point $(2,2,3)$.

Find the volume of the intersection of the interiors of P and Q.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016048/three-dimensional-geometry-problem/1016067#1016067). This is the 3rd time I've seen this question posted, yet I cannot flag it due to none of the previous questions having upvoted answers.

Comment: @VictorLiu I saw your answer but I don't think that is the way to approach it.

Comment: This question comes from the current USAMTS Round Two problem set ([problem 3](http://usamts.org/Tests/Problems_26_2.pdf)). This question will remain locked until after the submission deadline of 8 Dec 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call $A=(0,0,0)$, $B=(3,0,0)$, $C=(3,3,0)$, $D=(0,3,0)$ and $V_1=(1,1,3)$, $V_2=(2,2,3)$

Consider the planes $V_2AB$ and $V_2AD$. These planes define the angle of the intersection volume of the two pyramids regarding the sides $AB$ and $AD$, given that $V_2$ is further away from these sides than $V_1$ (hence lower angle).

The same way, $V_1BC$ and $V_1CD$ define the two other angles.

But the intersection of each plane give a line, which will be an edge of the intersection volume. There are four such edges, and the intersection point of these four edges is the apex of the intersection volume, which is also a pyramid.

The apex of the pyramid has the following coordinates:
$V_3=(1.5,1.5,2.25)$

Comment: Thanks, and then what do I do?

Comment: You know the way to compute the volume of the pyramid knowing the base surface and the height, do you?

Comment: Yes, thank you.